Strange behavior of function ConvertTo-Json
I'm trying to create json using:
$body = @{"type" = "page";"title" = "$Title";"ancestors" = {@{"id" = "$ConfluencePageId"}};"space" = @{"key" = "$ConfluenceSpace"};"body" = @{"storage" = @{"representation" = "storage";"value" = "$Page"}}} | ConvertTo-Json

And I expect to see something like this (of course, the values of the variables will be substitutes, I keep them for easy reading)
{
  "ancestors": [
      {
        "id" = "$ConfluencePageId"
      }
  ],
  "type": "page",
  "title": "$Title",
  "space": {
      "key": "$ConfluenceSpace"
  },
  "body": {
      "storage": {
          "representation": "storage",
          "value": "$Page"
      }
  }
}

Instead, I get something weird:
{
  "ancestors": {
      "Attributes": [],
      "File": null,
      "IsFilter": false,
      "IsConfiguration": false,
      "Module": null,
      "StartPosition": {
          "Content": "{@{\"id\" = \"$ConfluencePageId\"}}",
          "Type": 19,
          "Start": 72,
          "Length": 31,
          "StartLine": 1,
          "StartColumn": 73,
          "EndLine": 1,
          "EndColumn": 104
      },
      "DebuggerHidden": false,
      "Id": "cee857c2-d916-488d-ba55-2f455f116209",
      "Ast": {
          "Attributes": "",
          "UsingStatements": "",
          "ParamBlock": null,
          "BeginBlock": null,
          "ProcessBlock": null,
          "EndBlock": "@{\"id\" = \"$ConfluencePageId\"}",
          "CleanBlock": null,
          "DynamicParamBlock": null,
          "ScriptRequirements": null,
          "Extent": "{@{\"id\" = \"$ConfluencePageId\"}}",
          "Parent": "{@{\"id\" = \"$ConfluencePageId\"}}"
      }
  },
  "type": "page",
  "title": "$Title",
  "space": {
      "key": "$ConfluenceSpace"
  },
  "body": {
      "storage": {
          "representation": "storage",
          "value": "$Page"
      }
  }
}

What's going on with the ancestors parameter and why is it so bloated?

You've wrapped it in a scriptblock literal {...}. Change "ancestors" = {@{"id" = "$ConfluencePageId"}} to "ancestors" = @{"id" = "$ConfluencePageId"}

I expect an array element (square brackets) as a result, not just a nested element.

then wrap the hashtable in an array: eg. "ancestors" = @(@{"id" = "$ConfluencePageId"}) or "ancestors" = ,@{"id" = "$ConfluencePageId"}
